# get schema of table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

**Background**
my Procedure looks like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE c_sch.COMPUTETABLECOMMENT (p_BASETABLENAME in VARCHAR, p_sCOMMENT in out VARCHAR)
AS $$ 
DECLARE
  v_sComment VARCHAR;
BEGIN
  p_sCOMMENT:='Logtable for '||p_BASETABLENAME;
  select obj_description('myschema'.p_BASETABLENAME ::regclass, 'pg_class') into into v_sComment;
  
  IF v_sComment is not NULL THEN
    p_sCOMMENT:=substr(c_sch.ExpandComment(p_sCOMMENT||': '||v_sComment),1,4000);
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    p_sCOMMENT:='Logtable for '||p_BASETABLENAME;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

**Problem**
I want this procedure to work without me changing the 'myschema' manually for every table i run this procedure with.

**question**
is there a way to get the schema of a given table?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest is just to remove **'myschema'** from the procedure and then set the search path:

```
SET search_path TO myschema;
```

after that postgres will search objects only in **myschema** and you won't need to change the schema.

Comment: my problem is that the tables are in mulitiple different schema not just one.